# Android file transfer does not mount Android internal storage

Tags: internal-storage, macos

How could one mount internal storage of Android phone within the macOS terminal as a volume?

Comment: Hi, take note that questions directly asking for app recommendations are off-topic. Instead, we prefer the asker to just state the underlying problem that they want to solve and not putting any restriction for apps-only, so we'd appreciate it if you could [edit] the question, add some details and/or remove the restriction. Otherwise, you might be interested in our sister site, [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) instead.

Comment: @AndrewT. If it needs additional editing, please feel free.